# Bash скрипт некорректно отрабатывает переменные

Tags: linux, bash, centos

Хочу в цикле создавать папки и записывать в них данные

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 10`; do

  R=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)
  RANDOM=${R}

  if [ $((i%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ""
  else
    # nechetnaya
    echo "rnd is---> ${RANDOM}"
    mkdir -p "${RANDOM}" && touch ${RANDOM}"/myfile.txt" && echo "Current cycle is ${i}" >>  ${RANDOM}"/myfile.txt"
  fi
done
```

В отладке я вижу что `RANDOM` в строке `mkdir ...`  генерится каждый раз разный! Хотя я инициализирую его как переменную. И поэтому скрипт не работает. Как сделать чтобы `RANDOM` в каждом цикле был статичен?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не использовать переменную RANDOM? А использовать какую то другую

Comment: Интересно, а почему не убунту нет такого?

Comment: Типичное UB от нечтения документации. Ну и традиционно: shell — язык программирования далеко не для начинающих.

Comment: Наверное там bash отсутствует. По умолчанию там dash еяпп.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$RANDOM это bash функция не константа поэтому при ее вызове вы получете каждый раз разные значения. поэтому вам нужно перееименовать вашу переменную RANDOM на чтото другое, например FOLDER_NAME

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 10`; do

  R=$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)
  FOLDER_NAME=${R}

  if [ $((i%2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo ""
  else
    # nechetnaya
    echo "rnd is---> ${FOLDER_NAME}" && mkdir -p "${FOLDER_NAME}" && touch "${FOLDER_NAME}/myfile.txt" && echo "Current cycle is ${i}" >> "${FOLDER_NAME}/myfile.txt"
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Как уже говорилось:
`${RANDOM}` - это внутренняя функция Bash, которая возвращает псевдослучайное целое число в диапазоне от 0 до 32767
Более подробно: [tldp.org](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/randomvar.html)

---

О цикле: для меня остается неясной инициализация новой переменной с неизменяемым значением уже объявленной переменной.
Возможно стоит указать шаг цикла, что бы не применять дополнительную проверку через деление с остатком.
Для `seq` это будет `seq 1 2 10` - параметры: `стартовое число` `шаг` `завершающее число`
Установить шаг непосредственно в цикле можно так:

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i=$i+2)); do
    R="$(date +%s%N | cut -b10-19)"
    echo "rnd is---> ${R}"
    mkdir -p "${R}" &&\
    touch ${R}"/myfile.txt" &&\
    echo "Current cycle is ${i}" >>  ${R}"/myfile.txt"
done
```